# Child's viewpager destroyed/getting invisible after parent viewpager's page slide

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, adapter

I've a ViewPager (Parent ViewPager) in my activity with 4 fragments. One of the fragments implements a sliding ViewPager (Child ViewPager) with automatic sliding.

When I swipe the parent ViewPager to, say, tab 3 and then I go back to the first fragment which contains the sliding ViewPager, some of the slide disappears and some of it stays. When I slide the ViewPager (the child ViewPager) back and forth couple of times, it gets restored to its original state.

I assume the fragment state of the sliding view pager is getting lost when the parent ViewPager is being slid.

Here's the parent ViewPager's adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Here's the child ViewPager's adapter (slider):

```
class sliding_PageAdapters extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public sliding_PageAdapters(FragmentManager fm, int numTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = numTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup viewPager, int position, Object object) {
        viewPager.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle ar = new Bundle();
        FragmentHomeImages fragment = new FragmentHomeImages();

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                ar.putString("number", "0");
                fragment.setArguments(ar);
                return fragment;

            case 1:
                ar.putString("number", "1");
                fragment.setArguments(ar);
                return fragment;

            case 2:

                ar.putString("number", "2");
                fragment.setArguments(ar);
                return fragment;

            case 3:

                ar.putString("number", "3");
                fragment.setArguments(ar);
                return fragment;

            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

The child ViewPager is being called with `getChildFragmentManager()` here:

```
sliding_pagerAdapter = new sliding_PageAdapters(getChildFragmentManager(), 4);
```

And the parent ViewPager is being called with `getSupportFragmentManager()` here:

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one problem. On the parent viewpager call    [setOffscreenPageLimit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))(limit).

here *limit* is the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed. So set the appropriate limit based on your use-case.

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```